# Java FileWriter: To remove thread exception from code

Tags: java, filewriter

Program to create text file using **FileWriter**.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

class Wx {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String str = "Oh ho ho ho oh ho ho ho oh ho ho ho ohho ishq tera tadpaaweee ";
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter("text");
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
            f.write(str.charAt(i));
            f.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This exception is coming:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.ensureOpen(StreamEncoder.java:26)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:99)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:94)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:177)
        at Wx.main(Wx.java:10)
```

This exception is coming again and again, couldn't remove it after much efforts.

Comment: Well, the exception tells you "Stream closed". So have a look at where and how often you're calling the `close()` method on the stream/writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep closing the stream inside the for loop. Move it outside the curly bracket like this:

```
import java.io.*;

class Wx {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String str="Oh ho ho ho oh ho ho ho oh ho ho ho ohho ishq tera tadpaaweee";
        FileWriter f=new FileWriter("text");
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
            f.write(str.charAt(i));
        }
        f.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`FileWriter` implements `Closeable` (JDK 1.5) , so you can also use a `try-with-resources` statement that relies you from `closing()` the stream explicitly :

```
try (FileWriter f = new FileWriter("text")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        f.write(str.charAt(i));
    }
}
```